# Android internal storage reading file

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I have a problem with Android internal storage. I have created folder in package root folder calling `getDir()` and with `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` because I want camera app to write captured image in this folder. Anyway, I can see that captured image is inside that folder with `DDMS`. 
Problem is that I cannot read that file.

I tried to read file with this code:

```
File file = context.getDir("images", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
File image = new File(file, "image.jpeg");
if (image.canRead()) 
    Log.w("read", "can read");
else
    Log.w("read", "can't read");
```

And in LogCat there is only second message (can't read).

I have also tried to create `FileInputStream` with file name but I receive `FileNotFoundException`.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Reading file is correct but only problem is that when cam app is saving image to specified location, permission set by cam app to image file are `-rwxrwx---.` After changing permissions with

```
adb (chmod 777 image.jpeg)
```

I was able to read image. Interesting thing is that cam app is writing images files to `sdcard` with `----rwxr-x`.

Is there any way to change file permission in runtime?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the file's in the package root, and not in the `files` subdirectory? It's vary rare to put files in the package root itself.

Comment: In package root is folder _images_ and inside that folder I have files. I'm using internal storage in case if the device is without external storage. I don't know how to create folder inside _files_ with MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE so cam app can write captured image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put it in the default photo directory?

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
```

( From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html )

See also a more complete example invoking the camera app: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: hi, maybe you can include this in your answer because the most people want to show their pictures up in gallery after taking it and wondering why it doesnt work. Make a broadcast to register the file like this after saving it: `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath())));`

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() returns external storage. I want to save images to internal storage if external is not available.

Comment: @Sparky: I was unable to find another solution so I used this one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to [Android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) you should use `openFileOutput()` and `openFileInput()` to work on the internal storage... you are not allowed / not able to make dirs there. Android does it itself.. Those data will be cleared when your application will be deleted.